# How to run async function once in streambuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a streambuilder that Im trying to call a function that updates the read status on my app

```
void readMessage() async {
int num = 0;
final query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('chats')
    .doc(chatroomId(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid, widget.uid))
    .collection('messages')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.uid)
    .where('read', isEqualTo: false)
    .get();

query.docs.forEach((doc) {
  doc.reference.update({'read': true});
});

num = query.docs.length;

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .update(
  {"messagesNotification": FieldValue.increment(-num)},
);
}
```

and in my streambuilder im trying

```
return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats')
            .doc(chatRoom)
            .collection('messages')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          readMessage();
```

The issue is that it seems to be running twice, so if for example they have 3 unread messages its decreasing the message counter by 3 then 3 again. Im also not sure if this is how it works but am I right in believing that if a new message appeared in the stream it will run that method everytime so that incoming messages are marked as read when the stream is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamBuilder` widget rebuilds the ui with every change with the stream, so you need to wrap your `readMessage()` with conditional statement to decide whether to run this function or not

Comment: Thanks I basically wrapped it in a if(LastMessageReadStatus == false) run the method and that seems to be working

Answer (score -1):

You could create a boolean to check if the function is called

```
bool functionCalled = false;
```

Check if the function is called and if not you do your logic and inside it you set it to true. The next call won't jump in the if.

```
if(!functionCalled){
functionCalled = true;
int num = 0;
final query....
}
```